# Search with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search infomation about order details.

```
where @SDateMin as ShipDateMin and @SDateMax as ShipDateMax,
```

etc..

but when I execute my stored procedure, I get error :

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@spmin"

My T-SQL code is:

```
ALTER PROC sp_SearchOrderDetails
@FName NVARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@LName NVARCHAR(30)= NULL,
@Status BIT = NULL ,
@SDateMin nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@SDateMax nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@ODateMin nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@ODateMax nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @SqlStr NVARCHAR(MAX), 
         @ParamList NVARCHAR(2000)
 SELECT @SqlStr = 'SELECT O.* FROM dbo.OrderDetails O where (1=1)'
 IF @FName IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.FirstName like''%' + @FName + '%'')'
 IF @LName IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.LastName like''%' + @LName + '%'')'
If @SDateMin IS NOT NULL  AND @SDateMax IS NOT NULL
        DECLARE @spmin DATE =  Convert(DATE,@SDateMin,105)
        DECLARE @spmax DATE =  Convert(DATE,@SDateMax,105)
        SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.ShipDate BETWEEN @spmin AND @spmax )'   
If @ODateMin IS NOT NULL AND @ODateMax IS NOT NULL
        DECLARE @odmin DATE =  Convert(DATE,@ODateMin,105)
        DECLARE @odmax DATE =  Convert(DATE,@ODateMax,105)
        SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.OrderDate BETWEEN @odmin AND  @odmax )'
If @Status IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.ShipStatus = @Status )'
SELECT @ParamList = '
        @FName nvarchar(30),
        @LName nvarchar(30),
        @Status bit,
        @SDateMin nvarchar(50),
        @SDateMax nvarchar(50),
        @ODateMin nvarchar(50),
        @ODateMax nvarchar(50)'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SqlStr,
                    @ParamList,
                    @FName,
                    @LName ,
                    @Status,
                    @SDateMin,
                    @SDateMax,
                    @ODateMin,
                    @ODateMax
END
```

exec :

```
   DECLARE  @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_SearchOrderDetails]
        @SDateMin = N'10-10-2011',
        @SDateMax = N'10-10-2012'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO




CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails](
    [OrderDetailId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerTitle] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](22) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ShipStatus] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ShipDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentProvider] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Deliver] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderDetailId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ParamList contains parameters as they were named in procedure declaration, but later you introduce another similarly named variables. I've also changed datatypes, because `convert`s suggest that they are actually dates.

```
SELECT @ParamList = '
        @FName nvarchar(30),
        @LName nvarchar(30),
        @Status bit,
        @spmin date,
        @spmax date,
        @odmin date,
        @odmax date'
```

**EDIT:** I don't understand you last comment. To solve your problem you need to enclose code after IF in a `begin ... end` block.

```
ALTER PROC sp_SearchOrderDetails
@FName NVARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@LName NVARCHAR(30)= NULL,
@Status BIT = NULL ,
@SDateMin nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@SDateMax nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@ODateMin nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@ODateMax nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @SqlStr NVARCHAR(MAX), 
         @ParamList NVARCHAR(2000)
 SELECT @SqlStr = 'SELECT O.* FROM dbo.OrderDetails O where (1=1)'
 IF @FName IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.FirstName like''%' + @FName + '%'')'
 IF @LName IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.LastName like''%' + @LName + '%'')'
If @SDateMin IS NOT NULL  AND @SDateMax IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
        DECLARE @spmin DATE =  Convert(DATE,@SDateMin,105)
        DECLARE @spmax DATE =  Convert(DATE,@SDateMax,105)
        SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.ShipDate BETWEEN @spmin AND @spmax )'   
END
If @ODateMin IS NOT NULL AND @ODateMax IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
        DECLARE @odmin DATE =  Convert(DATE,@ODateMin,105)
        DECLARE @odmax DATE =  Convert(DATE,@ODateMax,105)
        SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.OrderDate BETWEEN @odmin AND  @odmax )'
END
If @Status IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.ShipStatus = @Status )'
SELECT @ParamList = '
        @FName nvarchar(30),
        @LName nvarchar(30),
        @Status bit,
        @spmin date,
        @spmax date,
        @odmin date,
        @odmax date'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SqlStr,
                    @ParamList,
                    @FName,
                    @LName ,
                    @Status,
                    @spmin,
                    @spmax,
                    @odmin,
                    @odmax
END
```

I would suggest that you do it even when if is followed by one line only, because you never know when you will have to expand that and it is way too easy to forget to put begin and end around new code at that time, because you are solving something else, not proofreading.

Comment: but my store don't get  result as act. can you help me , plz. my english isn't verry well . thanks!

Comment: @user1542080 Please post some sample data, expected output and DDL to generate OrderDetails table.

Comment: my OrderDetails table above .

Comment: @user1542080 Ok, what is the error? And cound you please post sample data along with expected result from your procedure, so I can test it?

Comment: [pre]ex : i execute my store, with 3 param as :
  FName = N'vu',
  SDateMin = N'10-10-2011',
  SDateMax = N'10-10-2014'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO , but no record is return [code]

Comment: @user1542080 No, no emails, sorry. But, if you comment out sp_executesql and put `print @StrSql` instead, you will get Sql Query you use. Then you can start removing filters until you see what is wrong.

Comment: `code` SELECT O.* FROM dbo.OrderDetails O where (1=1)AND ( O.FirstName like'%vu%')AND ( O.ShipDate BETWEEN @spmin AND @spmax )AND ( O.OrderDate BETWEEN @odmin AND  @odmax )`code`

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[sp_SearchOrderDetails]
  @FName = N'vu',
  @SDateMin = N'10-10-2011',
  @SDateMax = N'10-10-2014'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO<code>

Comment: @user1542080 Oh dear. You forgot begin ... end blocks to enclose code between if's. You should incorporate a habit of explicitly enclosing blocks of code in begin ... end even if one line only follows. Because of that your code generates `AND ( O.OrderDate BETWEEN @odmin AND @odmax )`, but these parameters are null hence nothing is retrieved.

Comment: `DECLARE @spmin DATE =  Convert(DATE,@SDateMin,105) <br/>
  DECLARE @spmax DATE  =  Convert(DATE,@SDateMax,105) <br/>
  SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.ShipDate BETWEEN @spmin AND @spmax )' `

Comment: Thanks you. i see my error, but i can't fix proc to run exactly

Comment: @user1542080 Please try the procedure again. I've changed sp_executesql.

Comment: <br/> My error ` SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.FirstName like''%' + @FName + '%'')' ` <br/> fix : `SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'AND ( O.FirstName like  @FName )' ` <br/> but i want to use '%' ...

Comment: @user1542080 you need to escape apostrophes around % if you want to use parameters: ' and o.FirstName like ''%'' + @ FName + ''%'''. Ignore space after @; I'm on a mobile now, I don' have backtick.